# Own CRM to get used by other application

Tags: grails, design-patterns, architecture, crm, software-design

We built our own CRM for our web application which has several other functions.
Now we got the request from the management that also another web application should use our CRM.
Our current web application is a monolithic one, which means that everything is in one big web application developed with Grails.

The first idea from one DEV was to create a REST API so that they can use our CRM functionality and customers are created in our application/DB and will always get synced back to their application.

I think this is not the best idea and much better would be to screw out our CRM from the monolithic web application and make a stand-alone version of it (microservice). This stand-alone version should then be configurable for things like DB, file storage, entities, workflows, ...

What do you guys think about it and maybe does one has another good idea for this specific use case?

Comment: We can not answer your question as it stands.  This is an architectural decision you would have to make for your project, your team, your requirements, ...  There are no silver bullets.

Answer (score 1):

If you can refactor your existing CRM code into Grails plugins then you can use these plugins in your current application and future Grails applications that need CRM functionality. We are using this approach and have 10+ Grails applications in production and almost all of them are using the same set of CRM plugins.
If you like to see how we split up the domains/contexts you can find the plugins here: http://gr8crm.github.io

However we are currently in the process of migrating all CRM plugins to separate microservices (Spring Boot and Micronaut) but it's a huge effort. My advice is to think carefully before you go that route. If you can break out isolated functionality in your current monolith into microservices step by step, then it could be worth trying. But replacing all features in your current CRM with microservices will probably take longer than you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Goran.
I missed out to inform also that the other web application is built with a completely different programming language (PHP and C++).
So maybe it is really the fastest and easiest solution to first create a REST API for the other application to use our CRM and sync between the two applications.
Of course, I think we should move out performance critical things like HibernateSearch, DB, ..